# Integral of an analytic complex function inside a closed disk

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, analytic-functions

I am trying to solve an exercise from  `Busam, Freitag Complex Analysis 2nd ed.` which also has a provided solution but I guess I did not understand it.

Here is the problem:

[image]

and the provided solution:

[image]

Why does $f_r$ converges to $f$ uniformly and how it proves that the integral vanishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is uniformly continuous on $\overline{\Bbb E}$, as a continuous function on a compact set. It follows that
$$
\oint_{|\zeta| = 1} f(\zeta) \, d\zeta = \oint_{|\zeta| = 1} \lim_{n \to \infty}  f\left((1-\frac 1n)\zeta\right) \, d\zeta = \lim_{n \to \infty} \oint_{|\zeta| = 1} f\left((1-\frac 1n)\zeta\right) \, d\zeta
$$
and all integrals on the right are zero according to Cauchy's integral theorem.

Comment: I just don't see this equaility, why we need compactness here and why two sides are equal?

Comment: @nondefinite: The compactness implies that $f$ is *uniformly* continuous. The uniform continuity gives that the order of integration and limit can be interchanged.

Comment: Can we directly say $f_r$ converges uniformly to $f$?

Comment: @nondefinite: Yes, that is a valid (equivalent) argument.